# java console applicaiton giving error for port 1433

Tags: java, sql-server, database, sockets, tcp

[image]

I have a java TCP socket listener console application. I get the following error on my console after some 150+ connections. the application works nicely with less no of connections but as the no. of connections increase it starts giving this error quite frequently. Don't know if it happens due to the MS SQL server or its a java caused problem please help.

Comment: have you used connection pooling? From the logs, it is clear that sql server is throwing the error. Worth checking the concurrent connections at your database end and also connection pooling from you application end.

Comment: @harshavmb- connection pooling is not an option on this applicaiton. the no of concurrent connections to the in the database is set to 0(infinite). Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i found a solution thought i should post it here.
The problem was solved by implementing connection pooling.For it i used [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)

Hope it helps.